# How to insert switch button value into database which is showing in recyclerview in android studio

Tags: java, android

I have a Recyclerview and it is holding two object first TextView another 
switch button from LayoutInflater. The value is coming from database into TextView. 
Now my question is how can I save TextView value into database on condition of switch button. If switch button is on then I want to save 1 along with TextView value and if switch button off then 0 along with TextView value. 
I have tried with this code but got null object value of Switch Button.

try {

```
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
                crudOperation.InsertUpdateDelete("EXEC androidTblSMSAbsentINSERT " 
                 +"" + tvClassId.getText() + ",
                         " + arrayList.get(i).isChecked + ");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.toString();
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Writer writer = new StringWriter();
            ex.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(writer));
            msg = writer.toString();
            isSuccess = false;
        }
```

```
public class AttendanceStdClass {

    public String CLS;
    public Boolean isChecked;

    public String getCLS() {
        return CLS;
    }
    public Boolean getIsChecked() {return isChecked;}

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return isChecked;
    }


    public AttendanceStdClass(String CLS, boolean isChecked) {
        this.CLS = CLS;
        this.isChecked=isChecked;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does the switch button show up in your code?

Comment: Switch button is showing in RecyclerverView in the name of aSwitch...
please check above I have edited

Answer (score 0):

please try to add ".toString" to your getText

```
`for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
                crudOperation.InsertUpdateDelete("EXEC androidTblSMSAbsentINSERT " 
                 +"" + tvClassId.getText().toString() + ",
                         " + arrayList.get(i).isChecked + ");
            }`
```

and check your quotation marks

Comment: I am getting error only in "arrayList.get(i).isChecked" not in tvClassId.getText().toString().